# How to refactor angular dependency injection for concatination and minification?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

I have written my angular application into seperate files for my readability and ways to easily find things to edit/code. This is my app.js that requires the dependencies.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'app.services', 'app.controllers', 'app.feed','app.directives', 'app.factories']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    ...
}]);
```

This is an example of how the dependencies are written out.

services.js

```
var app = angular.module('app.services', []);

app.factory('AuthService', ['$scope'], function($scope) {
    ...
}]);
```

However, when I try to concat the scripts, app is redefined constantly. I thought of taking out the var declaration but, I like to keep the files separate.

How would I be able to write this out where the dependency injections stay intact for my app.js, while still keeping the files separate.

Comment: You could just use Browserify...

Comment: I'll look into that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the constant re declaration of you app variable, you can take advantage of the module pattern: [Angular Style Guide:Modules](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#modules). 
Instead of explicitly declaring app in every dependency:

```
var app = angular.module('app.services', []);

app.factory('AuthService', ['$scope'], function($scope) {
    ...
}]);
```

You can define you service, component, directive, controller, etc as a part of the correct module:

```
angular.module('app.services')
.factory('AuthService', ['$scope'], function($scope) {
    ...
}]);
```

Declaring an 'app.services' module would only need to happen once.

See : [Angular Style Guide:Modules](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#modules) for better explanations.

Comment: you make a typo (twice) in your code : remove the closing ']' in ` ..., ['$scope'], function(...`;.   should be like this :  `app.factory('AuthService', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    ...
}]);`

Comment: I see! I believe this is really simple and a quick fix for me to implement. Am I limited to one method? One ".factory" for example? Or may I use multiple ".factory" 's  in one file?

Comment: I usually stick to a single declaration per file. However, I don't believe there is anything preventing multiple factories or directives per file.